# How Do I Downgrade a C++ Visual Studio 2008 Project to 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

How can I downgrade a C++ Visual Studio 2008 project to visual studio 2005?

Maybe there is a converter program that someone knows of or otherwise a process that I can undertake. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with 1800 INFORMATION on this, what's your actual issue.

Comment: Actually that's not really my question, I'm just interested in what kind of problems he is running into

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no idea how well it works, but here's an open source converter tool:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/vspc

that was an extension to the tool outlined in this article:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/vsconvert.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I always hate to edit the .sln/proj files by hand, since they can be so picky and problematic.  It might be easiest to just create a new project in 2005, and just copy all the code files back into it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need change the `sln` and `vcproj` files (including attributes like `ToolsVersion`, `TargetFramework`, `ProductVersion` etc). Some freeware may be available but I haven't heard very highly of them.

Answer (score 1):

Is your solution file in revision control system? Just see what modifications the upgrading to VS 2008 did to project and solution files and then undo them. There's not a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the open source that convert VS2008 project into VS2005.

http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/ProjectConverter.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can delete .sln file, then open .vcproj in VS2005, then save it as new solution. Since all project options are held in .vcproj file, that should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) to do it, with the following script or something like it:

```
s#Version=\"9.00\"#Version=\"8.00\"#g
s#<ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>#<ProductVersion>8.0.50727</ProductVersion>#g
s#<TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>##g
s# ToolsVersion=\"3.5\"##g
s#MSBuildToolsPath#MSBuildBinPath#g
```

Put that in a text file called "downgrade_vc9_to_vc8.sed", then call it with:

```
"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" -f "downgrade_sln_vc9_to_vc8.sed" "MyProject.vcproj" > "MyProject_VC8.vcproj"
```